# Add nullable column to SQL Server with default value of null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a nullable boolean column to an existing table with default value of null.

I have used this bit of script but it does not set the default value to null. it sets it to 0 instead.

```
ADD newColumnName BIT NULL
    CONSTRAINT DF_tableName_newColumnName DEFAULT(null)
```

Comment: Why do you need a `default constraint` on a `nullable` column, especially when you need the value to be `NULL`

Comment: I have 3 states for the value of new column. true, false, null. when the user fills out a form in the application. they can opt to answer to a question with yes or no or they can leave the question unanswered. reaction to No and not answered is not going to be the same. And I need this property of users to be defaulted as null, as if they have not answered to that question.

Comment: The default is always NULL - you don't need to explicitly add a default.

Comment: I believe in SQL the value of a field is NULL by default, no need to explicitly set it to NULL using a DEFAULT constraint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just ran your example code snippet on my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance and then inserted a record. It initialized the column to null, as expected. The next step would be to post the alter statement and the insert statement that you used.

I used:

```
alter table tmp1 Add newColumnName bit null CONSTRAINT DF_tableName_newColumnName  DEFAULT(null)
insert into tmp1(emp_id) values(9999)
select * from tmp1
```

After running the above, I used SQL Server Management Studio "Design" action to examine the properties of the new column. It showed that the "Default Value or Binding" was indeed (Null) as expected.